# .net deserialize xml to one of multiple known objects

Tags: .net, xml, object, serialization, types

Having tried searching with various combinations of ".net deserialize xml one many known object type"... and not finding anything that makes sense, I'm here now.

I get 1 of 5 unrelated objects (different schema for each) that may be sent to me and I need to deserialize that xml into the correct object.  And of course, the number/type of objects will grow ;-)
Is there a way to for the deserializer to match the xml content to an object, maybe reflection (just guessing)?  I don't get any outer xml wrapper around the serialized object telling me what it is, other than the xml content itself.  These are messages arriving from different systems notifying me of an event, status change, new order, ...

I'm thinking brute force at this point, xml reader looking for an identifying attribute that uniquely matches one of my known items, then switching from there to deserialize using the appropriate type.
That just doesn't seem too elegant.

Any guidance appreciated,
G

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
Stream xml; // Contains the XML to deserialize
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(MyClass1), 
    new []{ typeof(MyClass2), typeof(MyClass3) }); // Add additional classes here
object obj = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xml);

if(obj Is MyClass1)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (obj is MyClass2)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (obj is MyClass3)
{
    // Do something
}
// And so on for other classes
```

Comment: This did not work for me. The first type parameter passed into the constructor of XmlSerializer should match the root element of the xml.

Comment: I have to correct myself. This will work only if the first parameter is the same for the serializer and deserializer. For example if the first parameter is typeof(Message), then this will cause the serialized xml to have a root element <Message xsi:Type="TheRealType">. If the xml is in a predefined schema and you have no control over it, then this will probably not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML root element name (and/or namespace) is different for each type of object, you can use [XmlSerializer.CanDeserialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.candeserialize(v=vs.110).aspx) to check the root element name against the schema.

```
XmlSerializer appleSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Apple));
XmlSerializer bananaSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Banana));
XmlSerializer carrotSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Carrot));

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(file);

if (appleSerializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
{
    Apple a = (Apple)appleSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // ...
}
else if (bananaSerializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
{
    Banana b = (Banana)bananaSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // ...
}
else if (carrotSerializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
{
    Carrot c = (Carrot)carrotSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
    // ...
}
```